# In what order do cron jobs with the same schedule run?

Tags: 10.04, cron

Let's say that I have the following cron jobs:

```
* * * * * /path/to/taskB
* * * * * /path/to/taskC
* * * * * /path/to/taskA
```

Is there any guarantee to the order in which they will be run?

I've seen some people say they run in alphabetical order and others say they run in the order they are entered and yet others say they run in parallel.

I'm asking for 10.04, but if it changes in others, I'd like to know that too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order for Ubuntu is **top-down but in parallel**.

Meaning, for your example:

```
  * * * * * /path/to/taskB
  * * * * * /path/to/taskC
  * * * * * /path/to/taskA
```

1. `taskB` starts first,
2. then `taskC` *without waiting* for `taskB` to complete,
3. then `taskA` *without waiting* for `taskC` or `taskB` to complete

Ubuntu inherits this order from Debian. But in general this behavior may vary by Linux distribution/version and `cron` implementation. You should *not* depend on it to be the same. For example, in FreeBSD, the order is [**bottom-up!**](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2003-July/011538.html)

If the scripts depend on each other, best to call them in sequence, one from the other, or from a "master" wrapper script, which is the only one `cron` actually executes.

Comment: The *parallel* task order is valid for Ubuntu.